# PhpStorm/IntelliJ IDEA does not break on breakpoints in Jest unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, vue.js, phpstorm, jestjs

I have a [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) project that I'm working on in [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) (a variant of IntelliJ IDEA).

I've written unit tests that target my Vue components using [Jest](https://jestjs.io/). I am able to run my unit tests from PhpStorm. However, when I debug my unit tests, PhpStorm does not break on breakpoints that I place in my Vue components' code.

Below is my Jest configuration as I've placed in my Vue project's package.json.
Why does PhpStorm not break on my breakpoints?

```
"jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>./"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      ".*\\.(vue)$": "jest-vue-preprocessor",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^~/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/../$1"
    },
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,vue}",
      "!**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "coverageReporters": [
      "html",
      "text-summary"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
    "notify": true,
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./setup.js"
}
```

Comment: What IDE version do you use?

Comment: @oksana the latest which is 2018.3

Comment: This article helped me: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/starting-the-debugger-session.html#pause-resume

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without the project... I'd suggest setting `"collectCoverage": false` in your Jest configuration - does it make any difference? Instrumenting code for coverage usually breaks sources mapping.

Comment: Still happens even after turning coverage off and adding sourceMaps: true and retainLines: true to .babelrc :(